# Does attach-one-cell have a stable homotopy transfer?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy

Specifically, I am thinking of attaching one ordinary cell to an ordinary space in your favourite convenient category of spaces; so, given a cofiber sequence
$$ \mathbb{S}^k \to_c X \to_p X', $$
on the one hand, we'd be very surprised if the fibers $F_x(p) \to X\to X'$ had the type of finite complexes; on the other hand, the inclusion $\mathbb{S}^{k+l} \to F_*(\Sigma^l p)$ is about $k+2l$-connected, meaning the unboundedness of $F$ is unstable... so the question is: which feature wins, as $l\to\infty$?

Comment: cause for pause: we usually want the composites $f_* f^!$ to be multiply-by-fiber's-Euler-character; so if attaching of cells were *functorially* transferable, in most maps of finte complexes, we should expect the euler character of the fiber to be some non-integer rational; but that also doesn't seem to show up in the stabilization.